# Setting the svg image from a file contents but the image is in black color

Tags: objective-c, svg

I have an issue in setting a `SVG` image.
I have converted the `SVG` image by using `Inkscape` its been converted clearly. But when i am setting the `SVG` to an `JAMSVGImageView` the image gets black in color i have used `NSUTF8StringEncoding` while creating `NSData` of `SVG` file.

Please can anyone guide me through this.

Thank you.

Comment: SVG is kind of unstable format, imho. Inkscape though is unstable even more. You can try SVGKit instead, or taking different source - from Sketch for example. I use these combo when working with SVG, it works in 70% of cases

Comment: Currently i am using the JAMSVG framework and all the images are rendering properly with it but the problem is just with Inkscape converted files

Comment: I am not sure what @kerd means by SVG is an "unstable" format. That is an unhelpful comment. The problem is almost certainly that JAMSVGImageView has limitations in it's support for the SVG standard.  Try experimenting with the SVG save options in Inkscape. If normal saves don't work for you, try switching to "Plain SVG" or "Optimized SVG" in the Save As dialog.

Comment: thanks for the resolution i will check it and revert back to you.

Comment: i have used the plain and optimized svg example files working well but when the files generated from inkscape the images are in plain black color.

Comment: Then JAMSVG framework is able to load all svg formats except the formats made by inkscape.